# How to extract each different name from a column and convert it into a categorical variable with Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm dealing with an issue in Power BI being relatively new in the usage of it. I say in advance that for privacy implications I cannot share any data so I will be as clear as possible. I have one column that stores several  different names. I want to extract each name and for each one of this calculate the percentage of the usage having it transformed into a categorical variable. Thank you in advance

---

### Var1

### Var2

.
.
.                   - From this kind of column I want to create a statistics counting the occurrences of 
                      each variable

---

### VarN

Comment: You don't need to share your real data. Would be be helpful if you could add some dummy data in the same format as your real, together with your desired result.

Comment: Your question is not clear and it's highly unlikely to get a valuable answer to such vague question. Give a reproducible example, with amounts (not production data, but a made up example) and don't forget to include the expected result. So far it looks like you are asking about [grouping and binning in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-grouping-and-binning).